# How can I check CRC of multiple zip files with zip -T

Tags: linux, bash, zip, crc

I've got bash script for checking CRC of multiple zip files:

```
#! /bin/bash

fileFormat="*.zip"

for entry in `ls $fileFormat`; do
    echo $entry >> plikiZip
done

fileName=$(< plikiZip)

for file in "${fileName[@]}"; do
        zip -T $file >> wynik.txt
done
```

I don't know why, byt my wynik.txt contains:

```
  adding: mf.gov.pl_1133863230349.zip (stored 0%)
  adding: mf.gov.pl_1133863293588.zip (stored 0%)
  adding: mf.gov.pl_1133863748942.zip (stored 0%)
  adding: noweprzetargi.msgaz.pl_1133848724906.zip (stored 0%)
  adding: swps.pl_1133864085863.zip (stored 0%)
  adding: swps.pl_1133864308647.zip (stored 0%)
  adding: swps.pl_1133864438352.zip (stored 0%)
test of mf.gov.pl_1133863028119.zip OK
```

What should I change to have "OK" or "BAD" for all entries instead of

> adding:

and

> (stored X%)

?

Comment: [Don't parse ls!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1):

You always can use find command:

```
find . -name "*.zip" -exec zip -T {} \; >> wynik.txt
```

And here you can use `-maxdepth N` options to control the depth of finding.

Comment: @anishsane Thanks for the note!, I've fixed my solution

Comment: This is works for me but what if I want to do this for files in subfolders?

`ls -R $fileFormat` could be good (or not ;)).

Comment: @Thor1990 in your case is better to use just find command with exec option

Comment: I'll try it tomorow at work. 

`maxdepth 1` will "search" my top directory eg. `/foo/` and sub directories:
`/foo/bar1/`, `/foo/bar2/`, etc for zip files?

Comment: @Thor1990  yes:, Use it this way:
`find . -maxdepth 1  -name "*.zip" -exec zip -T {} \; >> wynik.txt`
     
#`Dot symbol` - means current path (also you may use full path)

Answer (score 0):

Replace following line

`zip -T $file && echo "OK" >> wynik.txt || echo "BAD" >> wynik.txt`

If the result is failure `&&` will fail and "BAD" will be outputted

If the result is successful `&&` will **not** fail and "OK" will be outputted

Comment: Unfortunatly, but in console I can see:
`root@WA-NAS 1133 # ./check_zip.sh
updating: mf.gov.pl_1133863230349.zip (stored 0%)
updating: mf.gov.pl_1133863293588.zip (stored 0%)
updating: mf.gov.pl_1133863748942.zip (stored 0%)
updating: noweprzetargi.msgaz.pl_1133848724906.zip (stored 0%)
updating: swps.pl_1133864085863.zip (stored 0%)
updating: swps.pl_1133864308647.zip (stored 0%)
updating: swps.pl_1133864438352.zip (stored 0%)
test of mf.gov.pl_1133863028119.zip OK
OK`
and file wynik.txt isn't created.

Comment: What can you see ? please be more specific

Comment: if you want to suppress the standard output try `zip -T $file &>/dev/null  && echo "OK" || echo "BAD" >> wynik.txt`

Comment: Now I see:

`root@WA-NAS 1133 # ./check_zip.sh

OK

root@WA-NAS 1133 #
`
and file: `wynik.txt` isn't created... Shouldn't it be that `"OK"` and `BAD` should be shown/written in file for every zip?

Comment: `>>` will create the file if it doesn't exist. Check if you have enough permission for `rw` wherever your trying to create the file.

Comment: I've got `>>` and I've got write permissions wher I want create file.

Comment: sorry my bad, just updated the answer, you need to add extra  `>> wynik.txt` after echoing `OK`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `xargs` and `unzip`:

```
ls -1 | xargs -L1 -I {} unzip -t  {}
```

and if they are subfolders `tree` would do:

```
tree -fai . | xargs -L1 -I {} unzip -t  {}
```

Answer (score 0):

As none of the answers directly cover how you would make a txt file with just `OK` or `BAD` next to each file path:

```
find . \
-name "*.zip" \
-exec sh -c 'zip -T "{}" &>/dev/null && echo "{} OK" || echo "{} BAD"' \; \
>> wynik.txt
```

Output

```
foo.zip OK
bar.zip BAD
```

To exclude the `OK` lines, miss out `&& echo "{} OK"` and the output will just contain any failed files.